# Automorphism in $U(16)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

Here $U(16)$ is set of integers less than 16 that are coprime to it.

We have to prove that mapping $f:x\to x^3$ is an automorphism.

Here I am not able to prove that $f$ is onto. Is there a general method for providing proof for surjectivness. I seem to be encountering this a lot.

Comment: you can either follow the hint of Aaron or, in this simple case, just create a value map...that takes about 2 minutes.

Comment: Yes I did that. But I can't do it very well if it is $x\to x^9$. It is not a very good method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** A map from a finite set to itself is onto if and only if it is injective, so you can try to show that the kernel of the map is trivial.  What are the solutions in $U_{16}$ of $x^3=1$?

Comment: So I have shown that function is injective. So that directly implies it is surjective. But this is only true for set to itself right.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar This is true for maps between sets of the same (finite) size.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The map $x \mapsto x^3$ is surjective because $x=x^9=(x^3)^3$.

The first equality comes $x^8=1$, since $U(16)$ has order $8$.

Therefore, $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection, since  $U(16)$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are very good general ways to proceed.  However, your $U(16)$ only contains eight elements.  How hard is it to cube eight numbers and reduce them modulo $16$?  (That is, never forget that direct computation also works and can be much faster than thinking about structure.)

Comment: I know. That's how I had done it before the answer was posted. But knowing the proper technique helped me solve a few other problems and also a few proofs. So imo it is still better to know the proper argument.

Answer (score 1):

actually, in $U(16)$, $x \longmapsto x^{3}$ is the reciprocal function to $x \longmapsto x^{3}$ because ${(x^3)}^{3}=x^{9}=x^{8}.x=1.x=x$ . As it is bijective, it is an automorphism.

In the general case, in $U(n)$, if $p$ is coprime with $\varphi(n)$, where $\varphi(n)$ is the order of $U(n)$, then $x \longmapsto x^p$ is an automorphism, thanks to :

1)  Bezout's identity : $ \exists (u,v);u>0  /  p.u+\varphi(n).v=1$.

2)  Euler's theorem, stating that : $\forall x \in U(n), x^{\varphi(n)}=1$

3) Then, $x^{p.u+v.\varphi(n)}=x$, so $x^{p.u} . {(x^{\varphi(n)})}^v=x$, so $x^{p.u}=x$

Then  $x \longmapsto x^u$ is the reciprocal of $x \longmapsto x^p$.

Answer (score 1):

As we know that ${\forall x \in U(16) , x^4=1 , x^3=x^{-1}}$, so the mapping is ${x \mapsto x^{-1}}$, we know that there is unique inverse for any Group element(here U(16)). so it is injective. Then for every ${y=x^{-1}}$ there is an at least one ${x}$ in U(16)

- ${f(x)= x^{-1} \implies x=f^{-1}(x^{-1}) \implies (f^{-1}(x))^{-1} = (x^{-1})^{-1}=x}$
- Also, in our case range of a function is same as codomain, then it is surjective too.
- As others mentioned above in case of U(16) , for any odd n ${x \mapsto x^n}$ is automorphism in U(16). and it is enough to show mapping is one to one.